# Consulta Ajax + SuiteCRM + Kreporter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estimados tengo instalado SuitCRM, y Kreporter pero tengo un problema. 
Kreporter no me ejecutan algunos eventos en Chrome y Firefox, pero en Internet Explorer (Edge) funciona perfecto.
El error que me esta mostrando es este:

```
ext-all.js:22 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
openRequest @ ext-all.js:22
```

La linea 22:

```
var Ext=Ext||{};if(!Ext.Toolbar){Ext.Toolbar={}}if(!Ext.app){Ext.app={}}if(!Ext.app.bind){Ext.app.bind={}}if(!Ext.app.domain){Ext.app.domain={}}
```

Comment: Seria bueno que publicaras la linea 22 de tu codigo

Comment: No es mi codigo, pero lo publico..no hay problema...ahora lo edito..